# Deserialization of JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following `JSON`

```
{
    "employee" : {
        "property1" : "value1",
        "property2" : "value2",
        //...
    }
}
```

to a class like

```
public class employee
{
    public string property1{get;set;}
    public string property2{get;set;}
    //...
}
```

In my JSON if I need to add property3 then I need to make changes in my class too. 
How can I deserialize to a class even though if I change my JSON(adding another property like property3).
The serialize/De-serialize techniques like `newtonsoft.json` is tightly coupled with the Class.
Is there a better way/tool to `deserialize` these kind of `JSON` in portable class in c#?

Comment: One way would be a custom JSON-Deserialiter, f.E. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base 

With a bit reflection magic, you could check all properties with a valid setter and map it to the JSON-Data by Naming convention.

Comment: Are you wanting to just deserialize to some kind of anonymous type so you can read the data without caring what sort of an object it is? If so the newtonsoft library will let you do this.

Comment: This question isn't really about deserialisation per-sae it's more about dynamically adding properties to a C# class based on dynamic input data.

Answer (score 1):

[Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) is not tightly coupled with strong types. You can deserialize the dynamic types too. See the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838261/how-to-read-the-json-data-without-knowing-the-key-value/30843096#30843096) ([How to read the Json data without knowing the Key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838261/how-to-read-the-json-data-without-knowing-the-key-value/30843096#30843096))

Answer (score 0):

You can try .net's **JavaScriptSerializer** (System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer). If some field is added or removed it deserializes object normally.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Registered { get; set; }
    public string s1 { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = "{\"PersonID\":1,\"Name\":\"Name1\",\"Registered\":true}";
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var o = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(s);
        ;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can use " Dictionary<`string`,`string`> employee" the above json can be deserilized.